# Open a browser using intent and keep it in foreground

Tags: android, android-intent

In an activity I have a button that launches an intent that opens a URL in the browser:

```
   Intent rrss = null;
                rrss = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse(MY_URL));
                rrss.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                rrss.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                startActivity(rrss);
```

When pressed, the browser opens correctly on top of the activity.

The problem is that the activity continues running in the background and at a certain moment, calls a new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MY_ACTIVITY.this, SECOND_ACTIVITY.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
finish();
```

This second activity opens on top of the browser that I have previously opened with the button.

I need the second activity to stay below the browser, and when I close it, then I will go back to the application with the second activity open.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can open again browser in the second activity in onCreate() or onResume() so that when you back pressed your second activity will open. In second activity you must check if browser is already opened or not. If opened then closed it first.

Comment: I think there must be a way to do it using the intents, what you propose can lead to a cycle of opening and closing of items.

Comment: There will be only one time of closing and opening of browser. I think there will be no such type of cycle.